# Xcode - How add multiple tags in Build Phases - Compile Sources?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, build, ios8

I need add "-fno-objc-arc" and "-O0" tags in Compile Sources - Build Phases to one class.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: try true tested method - google it

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode, select your project, select your target, go to the Build Phases tab, and under the `Compile Sources` section you can add tag for each of your classes.

[image]